# Random colors from custom palette on geom_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use random colors from a custom palette for each segment.

I tried both getting a random color saved on a variable called "hue" and then using

```
geom_segment(aes(x = x_start, y = y_start,
                   xend = x_end, yend = y_end, color = hue),
```

which didn't work.

This second solution works but it is not randomized. The IDEAL would be that the color is randomly taken from the palette without having the same color picked two times consecutively. It could be ABACBDA but not ABBACDA.

This is what I used:

```
geom_segment(aes(x = x_start, y = y_start,
                   xend = x_end, yend = y_end, color = as.factor(i)),
...... +
scale_color_manual(values = c("dodgerblue4",
                                   "darkolivegreen4",
                                   "darkorchid3",
                                   "goldenrod1")) +
```

Does anyone have any hint? I've been fighting with this a couple of days. Thank you in advance.

Comment: looks like a fun problem to solve (although I don't really understand the reason behind it), please share an example data frame which we can use for problem solving.

Comment: thank you for your reply. this doesn't really have any reason behind because this is just to try to create visually appealing art.

I made a few changes, which work but messed up the figures:

`colour_vec <- c("#001219","#005f73","#0a9396","#94d2bd","#e9d8a6","#ee9b00","#ca6702","#bb3e03","#ae2012","#9b2226")`

then while looping on each segment

`strand = sample(colour_vec, 1, replace = TRUE)`

and then on plot 

`geom_segment(aes(x = x_start, y = y_start,
                   xend = x_end, yend = y_end, color = strand)
....
scale_colour_identity() +`